# Google Wallet: Storing Order IDs in Database with PHP

Tags: php, android-pay

When creating a subscription, I log the `orderID` that gets created in the database intending to reference it later to handle a cancellation `postback`. My cancellation `postback` never seems to work however.

My `postback` stores the original order when it's created and then it tries to reference it on cancellation and update the database but the `orderID` is slightly different and cannot update properly.

This is the `orderID` that got stored directly from the decoded JWT in the database:

```
GWDG_S.886160e8-49b6-4f92-b485-9787c4cb4c06.0..0
```

This is the `orderID` that gets sent according to firebug in the console during the subscription cancellation:

```
GWDG_S.886160e8-49b6-4f92-b485-9787c4cb4c06.0.
```

This is the `orderID` that gets sent in the email to the user cancelling the subscription:

```
GWDG_S.886160e8-49b6-4f92-b485-9787c4cb4c06
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. How do I go about accounting for these changes?

Any input is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't seem to reproduce...in my *sandbox* :

### Subscription Purchase

**At test web page**:

[image: javscript alert box]

---

**Buyer's sandbox wallet**:

[image: buyer wallet sandbox]

---

### Postback Data

**This is the debug email I send to myself showing purchase and subsequent cancellation postbacks**

---

[image: email screenshot]

---

*Buyers* do get receipts with what I *believe* is the "incrementing" transaction number you are seeing (unless I'm corrected by a Googler) each time their subscription is renewed -

e.g. on 5th renewal `[...]6a6c4.0..5`

---

### Sample cancellation postback over a period of time:

[image: long subscription cancellation]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks for clearing up the .0..0 stuff. I managed to get it working. I've noticed the sandbox has been spotty... I have been getting 500 server errors a lot when trying to test my buttons. Is this common?

Answer (score 0):

Looks you need to normalize the orderID to the last format. For this particular one, the following regex will do.

```
preg_match('([^\.]+\.[^\.])\.', $orderID, $matches);
$orderID = $matches[1];
```